# How do I leverage HTML5 Cache Manifest with Google Maps Javascript API V3 for a faster experience

Tags: html, caching, cordova, maps

I'm currently developing a mobile application using html5 + phonegap, and everything is working well.. The only issue I'm having is that scrolling through a map on a phonegap made native app it's sluggish and slow, zooming on the map is quite slow as well. Is there any way to increase map rendering speed / tile loading using html5 and / or cache manifest file?

I was reading around and saw something about using cache manifest to combat these quirks? I haven't found any good documentation on it so I figured I would ask here?

Any help in speeding up map loading is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the google map JavaScript files into your cache manifest file. let's say your files source are

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.3&libraries=geometry&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Put the source values of your Google map apis into your cache manifest file and than check your application again, it might help you to zooming the map faster.
[image]

Put your own api's which you used.